# Can not get params['id'] from routing in a service

Tags: angular, angular-routing

Imagine the following route:

```
// student-info/120
{
  path: "student-info/:id", component: StudentInfoComponent
}
```

If I want to get the id in the component, It's correct

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }
ngOnInit() {
  alert(this.route.snapshot.params['id']);
}
```

If I want to get the id in a service, It returns undefined ...

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class StudentService {

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  getParams() {
    return this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
  }
}
```

[**Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w14tbx) : (click on the button to see )

Comment: Please use StudentService in component  metadata:  providers: [StudentService]

Answer (score 0):

Try to get `id` using this way

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute){
  let id = JSON.parse(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'));
}
```

Comment: It returns null

Comment: I feel there's a difference between getting value of params from an ActivatedRoute of the current component and a service.

Comment: It 's your right because If I get the prams['id'] in the component, It works correctly

Comment: Not sure whether that's a good practice to access from a non-routed component/service.